# Jquery - trim inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, innerhtml, trim

I somehow need to `trim()` the innerHTML of my content... so I have something like this:

```
<div>
     <b>test</b>

123 lol
          </div>
```

I basically want to rid of the white space that is ONLY between `<div>` and the next **character**, and the white space just before the closing `</div>`.

So the outcome would be:

```
<div><b>test</b>

123 lol</div>
```

Comment: Why? That's a sort of odd thing to need.

Comment: @jjj `$.trim` is _not_ a good option for manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
$mydiv.html($.trim($mydiv.html());
```

This should take the contents any element, trim the whitespace from it and reset it as the content.

Comment: You may be able to drill into the DOM and find whitespace text nodes and remove them more manually.  But jQuery won't help there, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: not that hard - look at `element.childNodes`, starting at `.firstChild` check for `.nodeType == 3`, remove the node if the `.textContent` property is all white space - repeat until first non text node is found.  Then perform backwards from the last child node.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why you want to do this but it seems like you are using jquery, so you can use the trim helper:

```
var $stuff = $(...the messy html you have above including the outer div);
var tidy = $.trim( $stuff.html() );
// tidy has no more div wrapper so you can do this:
return "<div>" + tidy "</div>"
// or this (but i dunno that it won't pad it again)
$stuff.html(tidy)
```

Comment: Two good answers, I've chosen the slightly more concise. Many thanks!

Comment: actually neither of them are good answers - the correct approach would be to explicitly remove empty text nodes found at the start or end of the div's child list.  But I don't have time to write that just now.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a jQuery plugin to do this. I created both a static and instance method for this.

You can toggle the `__DEBUG__TRIM_TYPE` variable below to change the technique. Each case will produce the exact same result. They are different ways of achieving the same result.

```js
// jQuery Plugin
// =============================================================================
(function($) {
  $.fn.trimHtml = function() {
    return this.html(function(index, html) {
      return $.trim(html);
    });
  };
  $.trimHtml = function(selector) {
    return $(selector || '*').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('trim') === true;
    }).trimHtml();
  }
}(jQuery));

// Example
// =============================================================================
$(function() {
  var __DEBUG__TRIM_TYPE = 1; // You can change this to values between 1-3.
  
  switch (__DEBUG__TRIM_TYPE) {
      // Option #1. Select elements by a selector.
      case 1:
        $('.pre-block[data-trim="true"]').trimHtml();
        break;

      // Option #2. Filter elements by a selector and their data.
      case 2:
        $('.pre-block').filter(function() { return $(this).data('trim'); }).trimHtml();
        break;

      // Option #3. Apply function to all elements where the "trim" data is TRUE.
      case 3:
        $.trimHtml();
        break;
  }
});
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.pre-block { display: inline-block; white-space: pre; border: thin solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>

<h1>Not Trimmed</h1>
<div class="pre-block" data-trim="false">
  Text not to be trimmed.
  
</div>

<h1>Already Trimmed</h1>
<div class="pre-block" data-trim="false">Text already trimmed.</div>

<h1>Trimmed</h1>
<div class="pre-block" data-trim="true">
  Text that was trimmed.
  
</div>
```